# How to return row and column labels from a non-unique value in a table in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Problem**

I have a table similar to this one below with 12 values (the real one has thousands of values):

[Showing A1: D5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1ys1.png)

[image]

I also have a list of the 12 values, with a column for the contestant (column labels) a column for the fruits (row labels) and a column for the number eaten (values in the table). *As you can see, the values are not unique in that they occur multiple times.*

[Showing G1: I13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHGYh.png)

[image]

**Objective**

I want to write a formula in the Contestant and Fruit columns that based on the value in the number eaten will return the name of the contestant and the fruit, without duplicating entries already found.

Note that the values can be duplicated in either rows or columns.

**Final product example:**

[image]

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBuFx.png)

Comment: I don't think that is possible. If the starting criterium isn't unique there must be more than one answer to the question based on it. Your final seems to tell a different story: Given "Alex" and "Apples" it's possible to return "8" - but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all Excel versions.

1] In "Eaten no." `H2`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(B$2:D$5,ROW(A1)),"")
```

2] In "fruit" `G2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(H2="","",INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($2:$5)/(B$2:D$5=H2),COUNTIF(H$2:H2,H2))))
```

3] In "Contestant" `F2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(H2="","",INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(B:D)/(INDEX(B:D,MATCH(G2,A:A,0),0)=H2),COUNTIFS(G$2:G2,G2,H$2:H2,H2))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have <kbd>Excel365</kbd> then give a try on below formulas. As per my screenshot

<kbd>B9</kbd> cell formula is-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER($A$2:$A$5,($B$2:$B$5=C9)+($C$2:$C$5=C9)+($D$2:$D$5=C9)),COUNTIF($C$9:$C9,C9)),B8)
```

<kbd>A9</kbd> cell formula is-

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C9,$B$2:$D$5))*($A$2:$A$5=B9),COLUMN($B$2:$D$5),""),COUNTIFS($B$9:$B9,B9,$C$9:$C9,C9))-1)
```

[image]